# Pixate to Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, pixate

i am working on designing Android App UI and i wonder if it is possible to export Pixate prototype to android studio ? have anyone tried or having an idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in their website(Pixate.com) to someone's question, they have mentioned that , for now its just a prototyping app , which means you just design it and show how it is  to others and currently there is no feature to export it to android studio but they have mentioned that they are thinking to add that feature as it helps the developer a lot, being a developer myself , I was also looking for exactly what you are looking , Adobe is developing a product with code name Project Comet which is going to be a competitor for Sketch 3 which is also a awesome prototyping software but its available only for mac, I hope adobe will be launching the Project comet to Windows as well and it would be of great help if they include the feature of exporting the code so that we can easily desgin and do the animations in these softwares and export them along with the code so that we can import in our IDE as this would allow us to spend more energy on back end rather than on front end ...

Comment: thank you very much Summy for your time and effort to reply to me , hopefully in next days we hear good news from Pixate.com.

Comment: i find this post that might be save time   http://exportkit.com/learn/how-to/export-your-psd/convert-a-psd-to-android-xml-ui-and-java